# Who owns this Email To Salesforce address?

Tags: emailtosalesforce

I have an Email To Salesforce address (emailtosalesforce@123...salesforce.com) that is associated with many workflows. Is there an easy way to determine which User owns this Email To Salesforce address? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer to my own question.

According to [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008ufqIAA), the EmailToSalesforce address can be found in the **EmailDomainName** column of the **EmailServicesAddress** table.

I ran the following query to get the info associated with the EmailToSalesforce address I was searching for.

```
Select Id, IsActive, LocalPart, EmailDomainName, AuthorizedSenders, RunAsUserId 
From EmailServicesAddress where EmailDomainName like '%123%'
```